# Measurability of a function which attains the infimum

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, convex-analysis

I have a question regarding the measurability of a function in the following paper:

https://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/638.pdf

Let $\phi$ be a surrogate loss function and $(X,Y)$ a joint random variable where $X\in \mathcal{X}$ and $Y\in\{-1,+1\}$. Define the risk for a measurable function $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
$$R_{\phi}(f):=\mathbb{E}\phi(Yf(X)).$$

Furthermore, define the conditional risk as follows:
$$\mathbb{E}(\phi(Yf(X))|X=x)=\eta(x)\phi(f(x))+(1-\eta(x))\phi(-f(x))$$
where $\eta(x)=\mathbb{P}(Y=1|X=x)$ is the regression function. Next, we define the generic conditional risk as follows:
$$C_{\eta}(\alpha):=\eta\phi(\alpha)+(1-\eta)\phi(-\alpha).$$ Then define the optimal conditional risk
$$H(\eta)=\inf_{\alpha\in \mathbb{R}}C_{\eta}(\alpha)=\inf_{\alpha\in \mathbb{R}}(\eta\phi(\alpha)+(1-\eta)\phi(-\alpha)).$$

Then the paper claims that optimal risk satisfies
$$\inf_{f}R_{\phi}(f)=\mathbb{E}H(\eta(X))$$
where the infimum is over measurable functions.

My question is related to the measurability. First of all, I want to check if my argument for the measurability of $H$ is correct. $H$ is measurable since it's infimum over continuous functions as $\eta\phi(\alpha)+(1-\eta)\phi(-\alpha)$ is continous in $\eta$.

Second, why does the infimum of $R_{\phi}(f)$ over measurable functions equal to $\mathbb{E}H(\eta(X))$? if for every $\eta(x)$ we find $\alpha^*(\eta(x))$ which attains the infimum and define $f(x)=\alpha^*(\eta(x))$ then this function attains the infimum of $R_{\phi}(f)$. However, it is not clear why this is measurable. Also, $\alpha^*(\eta(x))$ does not necessarily exist.